# The color of the scroll bar is white in dark mode in iOS safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, scroll

A web page with scroll made with React has white scroll bar in dark mode in mobile safari.

Normally, scroll bars are black in other web pages.

Why does this happen and what should I do if I want it to be black like in other web sites?

[image]

Comment: Likely a default style for the scrollbar in React? Otherwise, you can control styles just for darkmode - https://webkit.org/blog/8840/dark-mode-support-in-webkit/

Comment: I found that the scroll bar with style `position:absolute;overflow:scroll;` rendered in white srollbar in iOS safari.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the scroll bar by using ::WebKit-scroll bar https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. I can tell you are a new user so you may not be familiar with the rules. Usually you should provide your attempts so that questioner can get better idea. Also avoid attaching reference link directly into answer without showing your any attempts.